# Trivial image face processing

Tags: image-processing

How can I produce an image like this http://public.lanl.gov/herbertv/home/ ,
given the picture of my face as input?

Thanks

Comment: Tracing paper and magic markers would be a good start.

Comment: "Hey, guys, how can I do something incredibly complex in an unspecified language?  TIA."

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://vectormagic.com/home

Answer (score 0):

Try out this site:
http://www.befunky.com/

They have many artistic image effects in just a single mouse click